# How to import a mysql database in a drive of my choice in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I have been given a mysql database (.sql file) and I want to import it in my machine. I have a system in which ubuntu is installed in an ssd  (250 GB large) and I have a second 2TB hard drive for storing data.

Since the mysql database I want to import is almost 200GB large, I want to store it in the 2TB drive. Is there a way to select this, despite the fact that mysql is installed in the smaller ssd drive (under /usr/bin/)?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Hello treyBake, I barely have an idea about how mysql works, I have only previously used an already created database to work with in R. Could you please be a bit more specific about what to check on my.cnf?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have the option to have two data folders on their configuration, or specify datafolder for a concrete database.

However, you have different options to do it. For example, you can have two MySQL installations running, each one with their data folder, or you can use symlinks if you use MyISAM storage engine, or INNODB with the option separate_files enabled on my.cnf.

For more information about this, check this post [Can MySQL use multiple data directories on different physical storage devices](https://serverfault.com/questions/442913/can-mysql-use-multiple-data-directories-on-different-physical-storage-devices) from ServerFault.

Comment: Hello Sakura and thanx for your reply. To be honest I can't understand the details in the post, but I can understand that installing mysql only on the 2TB drive is an option. I don't care about having it installed on the ssd. Can this really work?

Comment: You can move your data folder in my.cnf. Stop the server, move your actual datafolder to another location in the new disk, and change it on my.cnf. Then start the server and it's done.